# MySql MVC3 EF Code First with Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a stored procedure created in MySql to return a resultset as

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetCount() 
BEGIN
   SELECT count(*) 
   FROM mytable;
END$$
```

I am trying to call this from my MVC3 application using EF CF as:

```
int count = myContext.Database.SqlQuery<int>("GetCount").First();
```

It is falling over the call to test in my application with an error ; 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GetCount' at line 1

```
Is this not supported using MySql?  Obviously the above works perfectly fine with MS Sql Server 2008.  So just wondering if this is a problem with the MySql side.
```

Thanks

Comment: Does anybody have any links to using MySql with EF Code First. I have google'd a lot and all I can find are either DB first or Model First samples, which do not help. Hopefully somebody on here has used MySQL with EF CF and will be able to atleast confirm that you can use stored procedures with MySql. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
int count = myContext.Database.SqlQuery<int>("CALL GetCount()").First();
```